# Referencing class library (.dll) from the same VS (2010) solution

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, dll, reference, solution

recently I have experienced a problem which is really strange. I have a c# VS solution which contains 2 projects: a class library (.dll) and a WindowsForms. I had no issues so far to reference the dll from my WinForms applications. However, now, after I reference it, everything works fine, in terms that while writign code the dll assemblies are recognised, until I try to compile and debug, where the dll is not recognised any more, though it is referenced.

Any help would be apprecited.

Regards,
D.

PS. I have tried both referencing the project and dll...Does that mean that the problem is at the dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have correct .net target on both sides ?
.net client profile / full .net

Comment: Hi VirtualVoid, thanks for your reply. I have both sides set to full .net 4. I just tested other solutions ih vae with the same setting and work just fine. i remember a case that i had to change it though. Should I try to put the class library to .net 4 client? many thanks again.

Comment: I just tried that as well. No luck, as some other assemblies I have complain. The strange thing is that I have another solution with exactly!! the same setting, in terms of referenced assemblies and everything and works fine :S

Comment: OK...for some reason the host (winForms) application was changing to Client profile...many thanks again VirtualVoid for openinng the eyes!